# VBNET paste datagridview to opening excel sheet

Tags: vb.net

can i paste datagridview data to opening excel sheet?

I searched for this topic on google but couldn't find an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called "ClipboardCopyMode" there you can select which things you want to copy.
Also, if you have Multiselection=false thwn you will always be able to copy only 1 row.